# Account for NULL and Blank as being different in comparison (issue caused by ISNULL function)

Tags: sql, sql-server, null

I'm looking for best practices here as far as checking for equality for fields which may be null or blank. For example, if I'm doing a comparison such as

a.Field01 != b.Field01 in a where clause, I know that I need to account for nulls if ansi_nulls is on, such as: ISNULL(a.Field01,'') != ISNULL(b.Field01,'') in order to get back cases where one of the fields is null and the other is not. However, since the database I'm working with has blank fields in addition to nulls (ugh), I'd like to do a comparison that distinguishes between NULL and blank, as I intend to use this in an update script which would then update accordingly (and set the destination column to be null). With the above comparison, if one field is blank ('') and the other is NULL, a row would not be evaluated as being different. What would be the best practice here to make suret that the following results are returned:

```
a.Field01 (NULL) != b.Field01 (blank)
a.Field01 (blank) != b.Field01 (blank)
a.Field01 (NULL) != b.Field01 (non-NULL / blank)
a.Field01 (non-NULL / blank) != b.Field01 (NULL)
```

Sorry if any of this is confusing or poorly communicated. Let me know and I'll try to explain better if that's the case!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where the confusion lies.  If you want to do not-equals between two fields, then this should do:

```
a.field01 <> b.field01
```

If either (or both) values are `NULL`, then this evaluates to `NULL` which is treated as false.  That seems to be the logic you want.

If you want blanks to be treated as `NULL` (which on closer reading seems to be the desire), then:

```
nullif(a.field01, '') <> nullif(b.filed01, '')
```

Comment: The issue I have with both suggestions above is that if I have two fields I'm comparing and one is NULL and one is BLANK, they will not be returned by the above.

I actually do not want blanks treated as null, but I also want to be able to return TRUE when one field is NULL and the other is not NULL.

If the data is col1 = NULL, col2 = ''

a.field01 <> b.field01 will not return, and neither will nullif(a.field01,'') <> nullif(b.field01,'')

Comment: @parrotsnest . . . And your truth table explicitly states that NULL is not equal to blank.  Hence, this logic (the second version) follows exactly what is being asked.

Comment: This will not return results (not what I want):


    CREATE TABLE ##TESTING (COL1 VARCHAR(5), COL2 VARCHAR(5))

    INSERT INTO ##TESTING
    SELECT '', NULL
    UNION
    SELECT NULL, ''

 
    SELECT * FROM ##TESTING
    WHERE COL1 <> COL2

    SELECT * FROM ##TESTING
    WHERE NULLIF(COL1,'') <> NULLIF(COL2,'')

The following will give me what I want, but it feels sloppy and unnecessary: WHERE ((COL1 IS NULL AND COL2 IS NOT NULL) OR (COL1 IS NOT NULL AND COL2 IS NULL))

Comment: How about wrapping the nullif statements in an isnull which converts any null or blank value to some predetermined value not likely to show up in your fields. ISNULL(NULLIF(a.field01, ''), 'nullo') <> ISNULL(NULLIF(b.field01, ''), 'nullo')